# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php-fpm" in /var/www/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample:50

Tags: magento2, nginx

I'm newbie to magento as well as in nginx. So I was following a youtube video which uses wsl2 in creating a magento project. So I got this error nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php-fpm" in /var/www/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample:50

And couldn't really find an answer. This is v2.4.5 would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You can get started with Magento with docker-magento, https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento is the most popular docker configuration for Magento. It will save you a lot of time in setting working environment.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Markshust Docker for Magento.

In a recent magento update 2.4.6-p1 the nginx.conf.sample was changed. See [changelog search for file nginx.conf.sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/727560d82199f6b938d1906e9d923e2dd40b490a#diff-157d2bc558ce473e66e013bb30759e55fe32bc9277626ec1f70bb60bb558296f). We simple need to revert this change.

1. Change `php-fpm:9000` back to `fastcgi_backend`
2. This should have changed all the lines with fastcgi_pass as seen in the commit above

**Background.**

I first changed docker 'phpfpm' to 'php-fpm'. This will automatically set the docker host name to match php-fpm:900, but gave me a 502 Bad Gateway.

When you need to define `fastcgi_backend` check the top sample in the file nginx.conf.sample. You can find the port for php-fpm using `docker ps`. It should be listened like `9000/tcp`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that NGINX can't find the server that is supposed to be handling PHP requests. In your case, this is PHP-FPM.

The NGINX is trying to route requests to a server named "php-fpm", but it cannot find this server. This could be for a few reasons:

1. PHP-FPM is not running.
2. PHP-FPM is running, but not on the host or port that NGINX is expecting.
3. PHP-FPM is running, but the network configuration is preventing NGINX from reaching it.

In the context of a Docker environment (which might be the case since you're using WSL2), "php-fpm" is often the name of the Docker service running PHP-FPM. Docker's networking allows services to reach each other using the service name as the hostname.

Here are a few steps to diagnose and solve this problem:

**1. Ensure PHP-FPM is running:**

In WSL2, you can check if PHP-FPM is running using the following command:

```bash
ps aux | grep php-fpm
```

If PHP-FPM is running, you'll see some output showing the PHP-FPM processes.

**2. Ensure NGINX is correctly configured to reach PHP-FPM:**

Your NGINX configuration file should include a line that looks something like this:

```bash
fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
```

This line tells NGINX to pass PHP requests to the server named "php-fpm" on port 9000. If PHP-FPM is running on a different host or port, you will need to adjust this line accordingly.

**3. Check Docker Compose configuration (if you're using Docker):**

If you're using Docker and Docker Compose, make sure you have a service named "php-fpm" defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here is an example of what this service might look like:

```yml
services:
  php-fpm:
    image: your-php-fpm-image
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

**4. Check your network configuration:**

If PHP-FPM is running and your NGINX configuration is correct, then there might be a network problem preventing NGINX from reaching PHP-FPM. This could be a firewall issue, or it could be that the two services are on different Docker networks (if you're using Docker).

To help further, I would need more specific information about your setup. For example:

1. Are you running PHP-FPM and NGINX on the same machine, or are they on different machines?
2. Are you using Docker, and if so, what does your `docker-compose.yml` file look like?
3. What are the contents of your NGINX configuration file?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. 
1. I somehow fix it by trial and error on configs.
2. I have docker but im not using it ( was following a youtube video)
3. Ive manage to got into home page of magento but it seems like I have a new problem where css and javascripts doesnt load and was curently looking for possible solutions.

Comment: What is the error you get in the Network tab of the console? most probably you need to generate the static content. Run the following and see if it works for you:

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I already did deploy static contents and indexer also give permissions to folder and there are too many errors such as this one [Report Only] Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://127.0.0.1/static/version1689369365/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src *.adobe.com unsafe-inline assets.braintreegateway.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Firstly is your magento url `https://127.0.0.1` or something else? Quick fix for the above error is to disable the `Magento_Csp` module, via command `bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp`, dont forget to regenerate the static content and generated files after this.

Comment: actually it was supposed to be magento.local.com as said in the video but whenever I try that I always end up in ubuntu apache page or nginx welcome page. I've also read about the magento csp but they said its for security is it ok to use it?

ps: now I got back to code 500 after running bin/magento setup:upgrade. sorry I was really a newbie

Comment: Lets try to fix URL first. `https://magento.local.com` should be accessible. Can you please refer me to the video you are following so I can get a better idea of your stack?

Comment: this was just recommended to me https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=GjlriwAZzxc&fbclid=IwAR3e0ZD9W-iD392YXFy1gh7U6Uu5_Regf6PCNKq-ZsbU0KEeduPUSdKp_U8

Comment: Do you have `127.0.0.1 magento.local.com` added to your hosts file on windows?

Comment: yes also in magento.conf

Comment: do you get a ping when you ping magento.local.com from command line?

Comment: yes I do get a ping

Comment: What is the error you get when you access `https://magento.local.com` from browser?

Comment: there is no error just an icon and image and I end up in apache2 default page

Comment: is `magento.local.com` pointing to magento's pub directory in apache's configuration?

Comment: i dont know that. but here's my magento.conf upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}


server {
    server_name magento.local.com;
    listen 8080;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

    access_log /var/log/nginx/magento-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/magento-error.log;

    include /var/www/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample;



} I changed the port to 8080 because 80 just redirects me to either apache default page or nginx welcome page

Comment: is your magento installed in `/var/www/html/magento`?
When apache redirects you to default page, does it change the URL?

Comment: yes it is installed in /var/www/html/magento. before it was like that it redirects me to other url but now it just stays in magento.local.com and still seeing apache2 default page